# Python: How to change a date in pandas which set as index

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I need to set the last date to today date. Example: 2016-05-18 to 2017-06-05.
However when I do `df.index[-1] = today`, it return this error
`TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations`

```
>>> today
0   2017-06-05
Name: trading_day, dtype: datetime64[ns]


           Stock      Open      High       Low     Close Adj Close  Volume
Date                                                                      
2016-05-13   AAD  5.230000  5.260000  5.200000  5.260000  5.260000    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.220000  5.260000  5.220000  5.260000  5.260000    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.200000  5.250000  5.200000  5.250000  5.250000    3000  

>>> df.index[-1] = today
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

What I needed is

```
           Stock      Open      High       Low     Close Adj Close  Volume
Date                                                                      
2016-05-13   AAD  5.230000  5.260000  5.200000  5.260000  5.260000    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.220000  5.260000  5.220000  5.260000  5.260000    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.210000  5.260000  5.210000  5.260000  5.260000    2000
2017-06-05   AAD  5.200000  5.250000  5.200000  5.250000  5.250000    3000
```

Only the last date is change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with df1:

```
df1.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 4 entries, 2016-05-13 to 2016-05-18
Data columns (total 7 columns):
Stock        4 non-null object
Open         4 non-null float64
High         4 non-null float64
Low          4 non-null float64
Close        4 non-null float64
Adj Close    4 non-null float64
Volume       4 non-null int64
dtypes: float64(5), int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 256.0+ bytes

print(df1)

           Stock  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
2016-05-13   AAD  5.23  5.26  5.20   5.26       5.26    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.22  5.26  5.22   5.26       5.26    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.21  5.26  5.21   5.26       5.26    2000
2016-05-18   AAD  5.20  5.25  5.20   5.25       5.25    3000
```

today appears to be a series with one row datatype datetime.

```
today
Out[36]:
0   2017-06-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Let's replace last index with first row of today:

```
df2 = df1.rename({df1.index[-1]: today.iloc[0]})
print(df2)

           Stock  Open  High   Low  Close  Adj Close  Volume
2016-05-13   AAD  5.23  5.26  5.20   5.26       5.26    5000
2016-05-16   AAD  5.22  5.26  5.22   5.26       5.26    6000
2016-05-17   AAD  5.21  5.26  5.21   5.26       5.26    2000
2017-06-05   AAD  5.20  5.25  5.20   5.25       5.25    3000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use rename

```
df.rename({df.index[-1]: 'today'}, inplace = True)
```

You get

```
        Stock   Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close.1 Volume
Date                                
2016-05-13  AAD     5.23    5.26    5.20    5.26    5.26    5000
2016-05-16  AAD     5.22    5.26    5.22    5.26    5.26    6000
2016-05-17  AAD     5.21    5.26    5.21    5.26    5.26    2000
today       AAD     5.20    5.25    5.20    5.25    5.25    3000
```

Change the code to

```
import datetime as dt    
df.rename({df.index[-1]: dt.date.today()}, inplace = True)
```

And you get

```
    Stock   Open    High    Low Close   Adj Close.1 Volume
Date                                
2016-05-13  AAD     5.23    5.26    5.20    5.26    5.26    5000
2016-05-16  AAD     5.22    5.26    5.22    5.26    5.26    6000
2016-05-17  AAD     5.21    5.26    5.21    5.26    5.26    2000
2016-06-05  AAD     5.20    5.25    5.20    5.25    5.25    3000
```

Comment: It will have `[2017-06-05 00:00:00]` which I just need to be `2017-06-05`. Also, if the last two dates are the same , it will replace both. Example:`2016-05-17` is also `2016-05-18` (means two 2106-05-18), it will replace both. I just want to replace the last one

Comment: Do you mean your dates are in a list?

Comment: It is suppose to be `2017-06-05` instead of today. Also, it is suppose to change the last date ONLY

Comment: it return `AttributeError: type object 'dt.date' has no attribute 'today'

Comment: Did you import datetime as dt?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145885/discussion-between-behappy-and-a-za-z).

Comment: yes, I did. 'today' is define as the question above